# AWK использовать в качестве разделителя комбинацию символов

Tags: awk

У меня следующий вопрос
есть в качестве исходных данных файл со строками вида

```
Feb 20 2019 16:35:32 | TXT | APP | SysGuard:1:1:SerLS:1 | 9166 | One minute timer - 16:35
```

из этого я хочу получить строки вида

```
SysGuard:1:1:SerLS:1,One minute timer - 16:35
```

например

```
awk -F"|" '{print $4"|"$6}'
```

делает практически то что нужно, но остаются пробелы до и после.

Такой вариант:

```
awk -F" | " '{print $4"|"$6}'
```

считает разделителями и пробелы, и |.
Как можно сделать разделителем именно комбинацию " | "?
заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Такой вариант:
>
> ```
> awk -F" | " '{print $4"|"$6}'
> ```
>
> считает разделителями и пробелы, и |.

на самом деле нет. цитата из `$ man awk` (выделено мною):

> If FS is a single
>          character, fields are separated by that character.  If FS is  the  null
>          string,  then each individual character becomes a separate field.
>          Otherwise, FS is expected to be **a full regular expression**.

т.е. `" | "` трактуется как регулярное выражение «пробел либо пробел».

чтобы вертикальная черта не интерпретировалась как мета-символ «или», надо её «заэскейпить», добавив перед ней обратный слэш. а чтобы в «эскейпинг» не вмешивалась ещё и оболочка, лучше заменить двойные кавычки на одинарные.

пробуем:

```
$ awk -F ' \| ' '{print $4","$6}' файл
awk: warning: escape sequence `\|' treated as plain `|'
16:35:32,TXT
```

упс. что-то пошло не так. *awk* проявил излишний интеллект и «отбросил» наш обратный слэш.

попробуем его удвоить:

```
$ awk -F ' \\| ' '{print $4","$6}' файл
SysGuard:1:1:SerLS:1,One minute timer - 16:35
```

вот теперь получилось то, что требовалось!

Comment: p.s. пока писал ответ, появился другой. но так как он короткий и неправильный, оставляю и свой.

Answer (score 0):

`man awk` говорит:

> Otherwise, the string value of FS shall be considered to be an extended regular expression. Each occurrence of a sequence matching the  extended  regular expression shall delimit fields.

Поэтому `" | "` вообще должно интерпретироваться как дизъюнкция двух пробелов.

Как насчет `-F ' \| '`?